# How to split a binary into N bit chunks

Tags: elixir

given some binary / bitstring

```
<<1,2,3,4,5>>
```

how do you split it into `n` bit chunks.

where n could be 1 bit, 2 bits, etc.

**Desired output for 6bits**

given above binary in bit form
0000000100000010000000110000010000000101

```
[<<0::size(6)>>, <<16::size(6)>>, <<8::size(6)>>, <<3::size(6)>>, ...]
```

Comment: What exactly you would want to have as an output?

Comment: @PatNowak updated question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to this is matching the rest of the binary with `rest::bitstring` (instead of `rest::binary`), which will also match binaries with partial bytes.

```
defmodule BitUtils do
  def chunks(binary, n) do
    do_chunks(binary, n, [])
  end

  defp do_chunks(binary, n, acc) when bit_size(binary) <= n do
    Enum.reverse([binary | acc]) 
  end

  defp do_chunks(binary, n, acc) do
    <<chunk::size(n), rest::bitstring>> = binary
    do_chunks(rest, n, [<<chunk::size(n)>> | acc])
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
iex> BitUtils.chunks <<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>>, 6
[<<0::size(6)>>, <<16::size(6)>>, <<8::size(6)>>, <<3::size(6)>>,
 <<1::size(6)>>, <<0::size(6)>>, <<5::size(4)>>]
```

Answer (score 7):

A simplest approach is probably to use `for` comprehensions with binary generator:

```
for << chunk::size(6) <- binary >>, do: <<chunk::size(6)>>
```

We can hide it behind a function

```
def chunk_bits(binary, n) do
  for << chunk::size(n) <- binary >>, do: <<chunk::size(n)>>
end
```

This gives the desired output:

```
iex> chunk_bits(<<1, 2, 3, 4, 5>>, 6)
[<<0::size(6)>>, <<16::size(6)>>, <<8::size(6)>>, <<3::size(6)>>,
 <<1::size(6)>>, <<0::size(6)>>]
```

Comment: Note that this will skip the last chunk if it's smaller than `n` bits: `for <<chunk::size(16) <- "a">>, do: <<chunk::size(16)>> #=> []`.